# Process.Start can't access roblox protocol

Tags: c#, process, roblox

I'm trying to launch roblox from c#, but it seems it cannot find the roblox-protocol.

I tried the code I use in windows run and it did find, but once I try it with Process.Start it says the file could not be found.

```
 public static string LaunchRoblox(string authTicket)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            long browserTrackerId = 55393295400 + rnd.Next(1, 100);
            TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
            int launchTime = (int)t.TotalSeconds * 1000;

            string url = $@"roblox-player:1+launchmode:play+gameinfo:{authTicket}+launchtime:{launchTime}+placelauncherurl:https://assetgame.roblox.com/game/PlaceLauncher.ashx?request=RequestGame&browserTrackerId=" + browserTrackerId + "&placeId=185655149&isPlayTogetherGame=false+browsertrackerid:" + browserTrackerId + "+robloxLocale:en_us+gameLocale:en_us";

            return url;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.x_crsf_token = GetXCSRFToken();
            Console.Write("Sucessfully obtained X-CRSF-Token: " + Program.x_crsf_token);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            string AuthTicket = GetAuthTicket();
            Console.Write("Sucessfully obtained AuthTicket: " + AuthTicket);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            string joiner = LaunchRoblox(AuthTicket);
            Console.Write("Trying to launch roblox with:" + joiner);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            
            var game = Process.Start(joiner);
            game.WaitForExit();
        }
```

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mkLd.png)

Comment: What are your project settings (x86, 32 bit, 64 bit)?  Most likely the project settings are not compatible with the game settings.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The function just can't find the protocol.

Comment: The function is failing while starting.  You are starting a executable and it is failing while loading.  It can't start because it is trying to run in a different mode than the main app.

Answer (score 0):

What you do works in .NET Framework. But your error message shows that you are using .NET 6.0. For any .NET Core and later you would need to do something like:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(joiner)
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};    
var game = Process.Start(psi);
```